# Creating smallest DLL file

Tags: windows, x86, 64-bit, lazarus, fpc

I have created a DLL file (library) with one assembler function. This file is 75kB size. How to make this file smaller? Like I suspect, there is an automatically included System unit. Can I exclude this unit from my dll file?

Comment: If we've understood what you're doing correctly, your best option may be to use a free assembler such as FASM rather than FPC.

Comment: Yes I tried to do something with it, but FPC+Lazarus is very simple to use. Anyway I will take a look at this assembler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I googled your Issue, as it came to my mind in Visual C++ there are Debug&Release Modes. 
So maybe you can try creating a smaller Dll using the Release Mode. I found some settings for this: http://bugs.freepascal.org/bug_view_advanced_page.php?bug_id=18632 

Maybe this helps you, but I'm not sure it will work because I didn't work with Pascal for like 2 years :)

Comment: It helped, from 75kB to 35kB. Thanks.

Comment: You may be able to further reduce this by eliminating any unnecessary DLL imports, and removing the C runtime library if it is present.

Comment: FPC, like Delphi doesn't use MSVC runtimes. winapi dlls only.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: I'm confused now.  Why is the OP using a Pascal compiler if he's writing assembly code?  Or does the word "assembler" have a special meaning in this context?

Comment: Free Pascal/Delphi have an internal assembler. So he is probably writing his assembler inside a pascal source file. The system unit is the core unit that is always included (comparable with libgcc and the basic file I/O and string parts of libc)

Answer (score 1):

1. **Why?** are you concerned about binary sizes on one hand, and have a **64-bit** tag on the other?
2. Debug info,   pass -Xs to strip debuginfo
3. Smartlinking, pass -XX  (dead code elimination) 1+2 combines to -XXs
4. Avoid advanced functionality. Do NOT set any $Mode, the delphi compatible additions to system will bulk it up.

If you want to further reduce you will have to edit the RTL source and recompile it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) to pack your DLL-s. I recently made a simple DLL in Delphi and here are some observations I made:

1) Delphi 7 made almost 2 times smaller file than Delphi XE3 (32bit, Release mode). Lazarus made the biggest file. So maybe older FPC can make smaller file?

2) I stripped all non-mine units from the library. I even replaced Math and Windows with my own, super-short versions. This reduced the file size about twice.

3) System unit is something you can't just remove, but there are ways to create your own, recompile and replace. I guess this is also possible with Lazarus/FPC.